# Sorting an Array Alongside a 2d Array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

So I'm using NumPy's linear algebra routines to do some basic computational quantum mechanics. Say I have a matrix, hamiltonian, and I want its eigenvalues and eigenvectors

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as la

hamiltonian = np.zeros((N, N)) # N is some constant I have defined
# fill up hamiltonian here
energies, states = la.eig(hamiltonian)
```

Now, I want to sort the energies in increasing order, and I want to sort the states along with them. For example, if I do:

```
groundStateEnergy = min(energies)
groundStateIndex = np.where(energies == groundStateEnergy)
groundState = states[groundStateIndex, :]
```

I correctly plot the ground state (eigenvector with the lowest eigenvalue). However, if I try something like this:

```
energies, states = zip(*sorted(zip(energies, states)))
```

or even

```
energies, states = zip(*sorted(zip(energies, states), key = lambda pair:pair[0])))
```

plotting in the same way no longer plots the correct state.So how can I sort states alongside energies, but only by row? (i.e, I want to associate each row of states with a value in energies, and I want to rearrange the rows so that the ordering of the rows corresponds to the sorted ordering of the values in energies)

Comment: you should probably check [numpy.argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

Comment: Use the indicies from `numpy.argsort(energies)` to sort the `states` array.

Comment: So once I get the indices from numpy.argsort(energies), how do I rearrange only the rows of states using them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `argsort` as follows:

```
>>> x = np.random.random((1,10))

>>> x
array([ 0.69719108,  0.75828237,  0.79944838,  0.68245968,  0.36232211,
        0.46565445,  0.76552493,  0.94967472,  0.43531813,  0.22913607])
>>> y = np.random.random((10))
>>> y
array([ 0.64332275,  0.34984653,  0.55240204,  0.31019789,  0.96354724,
    0.76723872,  0.25721343,  0.51629662,  0.13096252,  0.86220311])
>>> idx = np.argsort(x)
>>> idx
array([9, 4, 8, 5, 3, 0, 1, 6, 2, 7])
>>> xsorted= x[idx]
>>> xsorted
array([ 0.22913607,  0.36232211,  0.43531813,  0.46565445,  0.68245968,
        0.69719108,  0.75828237,  0.76552493,  0.79944838,  0.94967472])
>>> ysordedbyx = y[idx]
>>> ysordedbyx
array([ 0.86220311,  0.96354724,  0.13096252,  0.76723872,  0.31019789,
        0.64332275,  0.34984653,  0.25721343,  0.55240204,  0.51629662])
```

and as suggested by the comments an example where we sort a 2d array by it's first collumn

```
>>> x=np.random.random((10,2))
>>> x
array([[ 0.72789275,  0.29404982],
       [ 0.05149693,  0.24411234],
       [ 0.34863983,  0.58950756],
       [ 0.81916424,  0.32032827],
       [ 0.52958012,  0.00417253],
       [ 0.41587698,  0.32733306],
       [ 0.79918377,  0.18465189],
       [ 0.678948  ,  0.55039723],
       [ 0.8287709 ,  0.54735691],
       [ 0.74044999,  0.70688683]])
>>> idx = np.argsort(x[:,0])
>>> idx
array([1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 0, 9, 6, 3, 8])
>>> xsorted = x[idx,:]
>>> xsorted
array([[ 0.05149693,  0.24411234],
       [ 0.34863983,  0.58950756],
       [ 0.41587698,  0.32733306],
       [ 0.52958012,  0.00417253],
       [ 0.678948  ,  0.55039723],
       [ 0.72789275,  0.29404982],
       [ 0.74044999,  0.70688683],
       [ 0.79918377,  0.18465189],
       [ 0.81916424,  0.32032827],
       [ 0.8287709 ,  0.54735691]])
```

Comment: once you have the indices which sort the array use `np.take()` which showed to be faster than fancy indexing...

Comment: The answer is correct but in OP's example, `y` is 2-d.  It might be better to show an example of using `idx` on a 2-d array.

Comment: @SaulloCastro It may still be faster yo use `take`, but in numpy 1.9 the performance of fancy indexing has been much improved, so that little trick may not be worth it anymore. With any older version, yes, absolutely, anywhere from 2x to 10x faster, well worth it.

Comment: @Jaime thank you for the update, its amazing the improvement that has been done in NumPy!